# How to torn axes and ticks off in plotly? Equivalent to `set_axis_off()`

Tags: matplotlib, plotly

I wonder how I would turn the ticks and axes off in plotly?
The equivalent in matplotlib would be `.set_axis_off()` and `.xticks([])`.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You're probably after this - https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-visible (you'd want to set the parameter to `False`).

Comment: @miqh exactly, thank you so much! I browsed and couldn't find it in the docs. I really like plotly but found the docs really hard to search.